# switch to different user using fabric 

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I recently started looking at fabric for remote deployment. I need to switch to a diff user (from the one that I login as) and am not able to figure it out. Is it even possible, if so how? My current user doesnt have `sudo` permissions.

I tried changing following environment variables

```
env.sudo_prefix = "su newUser -c "
env.sudo_prompt = "Password:"
```

But fabric does not wait for password input for 'newUser' and fails.

```
out: Password: 
[oldUser@ec2-111-11-111-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com] out: su: incorrect password

Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: touch x
Executed: su newUser -c  -u "root"  /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/oldUser/upgrade && touch x"

Aborting.
Disconnecting from oldUser@ec2-111-11-111-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com... done.
```

Update:

As J.F. Sebastian suggested, `su newUser -c` works, but it prompts password for every command for every server, which kind of defeats the purpose of automation. Is there any way in Fabric to pass in same value based on prompt (in this case, its always `Password:`)

Comment: have you tried `sudo('su newuser')`

Comment: yes, I did. Problem is that oldUser is not a sudoer, so any sudo command fails with
    [out: oldUser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.]

Comment: that would have been most logical option to try, but unfortunately no :(

Comment: [the docs say](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/interactivity.html) that it should work without any customization i.e., `run('su newuser -c command')` works as expected. What is your fabric version?

Comment: Yes, only problem with this command is that it prompts for password for every run command per server (Fabric cant store this as password). Which in a way defeats the purpose of the script.

Comment: have you tried `env.password` in addition to your `env.sudo_*`? Though fabric uses `-S` in default sudo prefix i.e., it passes the password via stdin therefore `su` might not work if it reads the password from a tty directly.

Comment: `env.password` is for initial login. I am using it currently.

Comment: the docs say that it is also used for sudo

Comment: That is correct, sudo is for current user and hence same password would work. In case of su, its a diff user and hence diff password would be needed. There is no other placeholder for that.

Comment: could you change `env.password` temporarily: `with settings(password=newuser_password): sudo(command)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks [J F Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian), There were couple of catches.

1. Fabric makes connections lazily, so I had to make a dummy connection before invoking su to avoid context switch.
2. Pwd need to be stored in global scope and so that it can be reused. Fabric doesnt put it in cache for overridden su command.

Here is what ended up doing. Its working.

```
pwd = None
@hosts('myhost.com')
def test():
    with cd('/home/oldUser/upgrade'):
        run('ls')  #This is to connect aggressively (instead of lazily)
        global pwd  #Change the scope of pwd
        if pwd is None:
            pwd = getpass.getpass('enter password for newUser')

        execute(su, pwd, 'newUser', 'touch x')  
        run ('ls')
        execute(su, pwd, 'newUser', 'rm x') 
        run ('ls')

def su(pwd, user, command):
    with settings(
        password= "%s" % pwd,
        sudo_prefix="su %s -c " % user,
        sudo_prompt="Password:"
        ):
        sudo(command)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you can't ssh as `newuser` and can't use `sudo(command, user='newuser')`:

```
import getpass # just for demonstration
from fabric.api import sudo, settings

def su(user, command):
    with settings(password=getpass.getpass('enter password for %s: ' % user),
                  sudo_prefix="su %s -c " % user,
                  sudo_prompt="Password:"):
        sudo(command)
```