# Su - root with python fabric

Tags: python, fabric

How can I "su -" and pass the root password with fabric?  My current job doesn't give us sudoers, but instead uses su - to root(stupid in my opinion). On googling I haven't found a simple(or any working) answer to this.

My normal code for fabric is like:

```
from fabric.api import *
env.host_string="10.10.10.10"
env.user="mahuser"
env.password="mahpassword"
run('whoami')
```

Need to be able to

```
run('su -')
```

and have it pass my password.

Comment: Here is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12648391/202504

Comment: why do you need to su to the root password? Why not just use fabric's builtin `sudo` function?

Comment: My company's security team are idiots, and won't give us sudo access.....yet for some reason they are fine with us having the root password.  Going to just keep fighting them to give us sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I hear you saying that your policy does not permit use of "sudo" command. Understood.

But what HAPPENS when you try using Fabric sudo()?  Please try it and report back.

I don't think sudo() "requires" a sudo prompt at the other end. What sudo() is is a run() command which anticipates a password prompt and attempts to respond to it.  That's all.

So in your case, "sudo('su -')".  If it fails, try "sudo('su - -c whoami') to see if you have any temporary success at all.

The point I want to make is run() and sudo()sudo() and run() are nearly identical EXCEPT that sudo() will anticipate a server prompt, then answer it. That's the difference.

Conversely, I had a different problem recently, where I was trying to suppress the prompt for sudo() using SSH keys. I couldn't get my head around why Fabric was prompting for the password when bash+ssh wasn't. The docs weren't clear, but eventually I realized that the prompt was MY doing because I thought that sudo level commands required sudo(). Untrue. If your command requires no prompt, use run() and if your command requires password input, use sudo().

Worst case, if sudo() doesn't work for you, it will have still created an AttributeObject of the SSH connection. You may or may not be able to then push some "input" into the stdin attribute of that object (I'm not sure this is correct, it's untested. But that's what you'd do with Paramiko, blindly send text down the connection's STDIN and it gets picked up by the prompt).

Absolute worst case, call sudo()/run() on "expect" command which WILL work, but may not be the simplest cleanest solution.