# Fabric su with sudo

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following procedure that I need to implement in Fabric:

1. su newuser
2. cd /newuser/bin/
3. sudo ./script.sh

I tried to implement the solution here
[switch to different user using fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641514/switch-to-different-user-using-fabric) 
but it doesn't work for me.

I get "Must be logged on as root or user with sudo privileges" which means sudo
didn't work for some reason.
Strangely enough when I put the sudo in the sending command ie:

execute(su, pwd, 'newUser', sudo('./script.sh'))

it seems it works but not as newUser but as been executed by the old user.

Any ideas ? Is there another implementation I can use ?

Comment: I think it fails on the first stage. You need to call `sudo su newuser`...

Comment: The `sudo su newuser` didn't work either Willem. I have tried that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I tried many things around and not being able to find a solution,
I decided to have a workaround.
I ssh directly with the new user so to avoid the su and then sudo. 
Of course this only works if your newuser can ssh to the node